# Appending to a non existing nested defaultdict entry

Tags: python

I'm creating a tiny logger package like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict
nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
logger = nested_dict()
```

I can then use it in any script to create nested entries like so:

```
from utils.logger import logger
logger["some"]["key"] = 1
```

However I want to be able to call the append method as well to then automatically create the keys and adding the first entry

```
from utils.logger import logger
logger["some"]["key"].append(1)
```

This does not work and, obviously, throws the following error:

> AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'

I'm not quite sure how to extend my logger in such a way to handle this feature without breaking the simple API/usage. Any ideas?

In other words, I want my logger to infer that it needs to create a list as the value for that key.

Comment: `.append` is a *list* method, it doesn't make sense for a dictionary. What would you expect as the result?

Comment: @jonrsharpe As stated in the question, I want to extend my logger in such a way that it _can_ handle this feature. So that it automatically infers to create a list as the value for that specific key

Comment: It can't, the `.append` is called *after* the object is created; unless you know the depth up-front (as the current answer shows) you'll have to change the API. Or you could create a custom object that can change its internal container based on the methods you call on it, but that will add a lot of complexity.

Comment: Ok fair enough, then I will check before hand if the key exists and create an empty list in place, instead.

Comment: Oh my bad I overlooked it

Comment: If depth of your defaultdict is always two, you can set the inner dict to have `[]` as default.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the lambda function to set the default values so that if the key doesn't exist, it will create `key: default value` instead of throwing a `KeyError`.
You can set it to `int`, `float`, a concrete integer or string or even `list()` and [more](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects).

```
logger = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: list()))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, `lambda: list()` can be shortened to just `list`.

Comment: Not sure I am very qualified for that but I will give it a try. Also, when I use `list` instead of `list()`, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Ortix92 If my answer is correct and did help you achieve your goal, please remind to mark it as accepted so it can help the community in the future.